# File monitor- c# or c++

Tags: c#, monitoring, etw

I am developing a file monitor to monitor file access of any exe. I monitor that exe for any file it opens/closes,reads/writes and collect the stats.

I am total newcomer to ETW (as from my research, it does not look there is any other way to do this.)

while I have been able to get some c++ code going, my client would prefer a c# solution.is there enough support in c# to monitor file io?

the samples in msdn are c++/c specific. I read vance Morrison's blogs.but its beyond me at the moment and  they don't seem to suit "nt kernel logging sessions/ monitor file io" scenarios.

can anyone give me a simple sample or point me to a useful link ? any inputs is welcome on this.

Comment: Any C# solution is going to have to use P/Invoke a lot to access the Windows API functions that you'll need to call. Perhaps you could write a DLL in C/C++ that does what you need and export from it some simple functions that provide an interface, then write a wrapper class in C# that uses P/Invoke to call those functions.

Comment: that's what I am doing currently..I am just curious to see the support offered by c# 4.0 4.5 and if that's the case,code will be more simple and  pinvoke is not required..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows, ultimately any file access is granted, by the underlying winapi. See CreateFile and familly. These functions are hook-able by [Microsoft Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) (though it is intended for instrumention purposes). There are also a handfull of other libraries for this sort of purposes e.g. easyhook.

Comment: I am monitoring an exe..will they be useful in this context-i.e pick up file io events ?.....thanks for the info mate. means more research :)

Comment: Simply put such hook functions means they will first be dispatched to your own function, prior to actually calling, the function supplied by the os - you can even adjust parameters if you wish and alter the behaviour. In short yes - they can be used in your scenario.

Comment: oh that's great!...any other useful sample/link on this lib that you can provide me? I will search anyway

Comment: ,I read some articles..from my understanding, I have to write a dll naming the to-be-hooked functions and user defined hook procedures.Then I inject that dll into the required process.is this the way to do it?

Comment: Correct, that is the basic outline of it. I have never done it on third-party executable files though but the code on http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30140/API-Hooking-with-MS-Detours, specificially under the CreateRemoteThread is what you need for this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Comment: I am well aware this class.but it monitors a file for changes...not the external accesses of this file..that's what I am lookin for.